# Calling another view in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to call a view programatically in [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29), but I have no success.

I've found this for [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C):

```
EnterNameController *newEnterNameController = [[EnterNameController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EnterName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newEnterNameController animated:YES];
```

How can I do that in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
            let vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menu") as UIViewController;
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Answer (score 6):

The exact similar method is there in Swift:

```
let newEnterNameController = EnterNameController(nibName: "nibName", bundle: nil)
self.navigationController.pushViewController(newEnterNameController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Can't resolve `EnterNameController` and `controller`. Am i missing an import?

Comment: You need to cast `EnterNameController` to `UIViewController`

Comment: @KumarKL is it required type casting. Not even tried

Comment: try like this `let newEnterNameController = EnterNameController(nibName: "nibName", bundle: nil) as UIViewController`

Comment: If `EnterNameController` is a user-defined Objective C class, have you added its import to your bridging header?  See [the interop docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).  All imports in the Objective C bridging header are made available to your swift code.  It _should_ be autogenerated as <module name>-Bridging-Header.h, but if not, you can set the "Objective C Bridging Header" build setting to the path (relative to the project root) of a header you create.

Comment: still getting the same error.

@sefnap sorry i'm not familiar with both objective-c and swift. Can you help me through doing what you said?

Comment: @ÇağdaşSalur, sure.  Basically, if you want to reference an Objective C class in your swift code, you need to import it.  The standard frameworks are already set up in modules for you, so you can just `import UIKit` and have all the UIKit classes available.  For your own classes that are written in Objective C, you have a "bridging header" which is written in Objective C.  Inside of it, you `#import` the header files for the classes you want to use in Swift.  Then the swift compiler will make those classes available to all your swift code.

Answer (score 0):

```
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifier") as! ProductListVC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```